# Centering horizontal navigation bar

Tags: html, css

How can it be that there are so many answers on this topic and I still can't figure this out? I've been fiddling with the CSS on jsfiddle for hours and I still don't understand why my navigation bar won't center without going into a vertical list.

The html:

```
<div class='nav'>
<ul class='menu' id='menu'>
<li><a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'>home</a></li>
<li><a class='drop-ctg' href='a'>MAKEUP</a>
   <ul>
     <li><a href='a'>EYES</a></li>
     <li><a href='a'>LIPS</a></li>
     <li><a href='a'>FACE</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='a'>SKINCARE</a></li>
<li><a href='a'>LIFESTYLE</a></li>
<li><a href='a'>DIY</a></li>
<li><a href='a'>CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS, I think:

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  outline:0;
}
.nav {
  width:950px;
  height:auto;
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  margin:10px auto 5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.menu {
  width:auto;
  list-style:none;
  font:$pagenavifont;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.menu a {
  float:left;
  color:#999;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  width:auto;
  line-height:36px;
  padding:0 20px;
}
.menu a:hover,li.menuhover a{
  color:#111;
}
.menu li {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:auto;
}
.menu li:last-child {
  background:none;
}
.menu ul{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:36px;
  left:0;
  background:#fbfbfb;
  display:none;
  list-style:none;
}
.menu ul li{
  float:none;
  border-top:1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-right:1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-left:1px solid #e3e3e3;
  width:auto;
  background:none;
}
.menu ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom:1px solid #e3e3e3
}
.menu ul li a{
  float:none;
  display:block;
  background:none;
  line-height:36px;
  min-width:137px;
  width:auto;
  text-align:left;
  padding-left:10px;
  color:#444;
}
.menu ul li a:hover{
  background:#fdfdfd;
  color:#777;
}
```

I just started my blog today, and so far I've learned that getting rid of floats and putting inline-block might help, but there are so many that I really don't get which code applies to what. Any help is appreciated!

Here's the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/vFDrV/9/
Here's the link to my blog: http://theprettyfoxes.blogspot.com/

Comment: I don't know if I'm right but, your <ul> is the same as the parent width. try putting `width: 482px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly your question, its quite simple.

Add the follow code to your **menu css class**.

```
.menu { /* applying to a ul element */ 
    /* ... your code ... */ 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can read more about this at the Mozilla Docs

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

What it's going on when we add *"inline-block"* is this:

> The element generates a block element box that will be flowed with
>   surrounding content as if it were a single inline box (behaving much
>   like a replaced element would)

Thats all!

Comment: thank you, thank you! This worked perfectly. I'd love to say I facepalmed from the obvious-ness  of this solution, but really, who am I kidding...

Comment: @user3496267 you are welcome my friend! I updated my answer to add an explanation about inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

remove float from following:

```
.menu a {
    /*float: left;*/
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.menu li {
    position: relative;
    /*float: left;*/
    width: auto;
    display: inline; /* <- add this */
}
```